# Using Map function to import files/library on JS ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about import on JS.
There is a list of JSON which contain files & path.

```json
[
   {
      "name":"example",
      "path":"./value/example.json"
   },
   {
      "name":"example2",
      "path":"./value/example2.json"
   }
]
```

Can I use `map()` to import those files? The result should be like this:

```js
import example from './value/example.json';
import example 2 from './value/example2.json';
```

Seems it's too lengthy when I have 10+ & 20+ on the list.

Comment: No. `import` declarations cannot be dynamic (unless you generate the code). Why do you store these as JSON in the first place?

Comment: You could use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like this:

```
const importItems = [
  {
    name: "example",
    path: "./value/example.json"
  },
  {
    name: "example2",
    path: "./value/example2.json"
  }
]
importItems.map((imp) => {
  import(imp.path).then((item) => {
      // Use your exported item, item.default or item.example...
  });
})
```